# Cuando des un discurso, ¿deberías usar el singular tú o el plural vosotros?

Tags: gramática, plurales

En inglés, en un discurso puedes decir, por ejemplo:

> I want to say to you *(singular)* tonight that we must take action... you all (plural) must be strong

En otras palabras, puedes mezclar el singular *tú* y el plural *vosotros*, y a nadie le importaría. ¿Es lo mismo en español? O se prefiere usar una sola forma, con consistencia.

El ejemplo se traduce más o menos así:

> Quiero decirte *(singular)* esta noche que debemos hacer algo... tienen (plural) que ser fuerte

Comment: En el inglés estándar, *you* puede ser singular o plural y *you all* plural individual — *cada uno de vosotros/Vds.*. Así que no hay cambio de singular a plural. (En mi dialecto, *you* solo tiene valor de singular, y lo que has escrito me sonaría raro en él)

Comment: ¿Debería usar el subjunctivo "des" en este caso? No es el futuro sino un actividad habtiual por lo qual creo "da" cabe mejor.

Comment: Dónde está el uso de "des"?

Comment: @james en tu título

Comment: Pero, james, "I want to say to you" en realidad es "I want to say to you (plural)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bajo mi punto de vista, en general se debe hablar en la segunda persona del plural. 
Sólo en determinadas ocasiones puedes hablar en segunda persona del singular para referirte a los asistentes de una manera más personal.

> Mi nombre es Josep Bernad y esta noche quiero **transmitiros** mis pensamientos [...] y si tú, chico de 20-30 años, **quieres** crear una empresa, ¡adelante! ¡**Persigue** tus sueños!

Comment: ah veo la diferencia, gracias!